# Do I need anything else for this drone build?

Tags: quadcopters, propellers, building, diy, compatibility

So far, I have these parts as all I need for a drone build. Is there anything else that I need or should have?

- Flight controller: [DJI Naza-M Lite](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PA7W380)
- TX/RX: [FS-i6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CWBQ2HM)
- Drone body: [F450](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0776WLHX7)
- Motors: [2212 920kv](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075DD16LK)
- Motor controllers: [40A ESC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08K4LHQNZ)
- Props: [1045 Props](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0823NNTKD)

Is this everything I need to fully complete this build?

Answer (score 2):

This has all of the items needed to build a drone.

1. Flight Controller
2. Remote Control and Receiver
3. Frame
4. Motors - 4
5. Electronic Speed Controllers - 4
6. Propellers - 2 CW, 2 CCW

Assemble it and you will need a battery to fly it.
Looking forward to seeing how it turns out!

Comment: This will be my first DIY drone, I'm excited too!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this frame has a power distribution board built in, and these ESCs have a 5v BEC built in, while many other frames will need a separate PDB with 5v supply. Also there are little things like a battery plug for the drone, heat shrink tube, velcro and a velcro strap for the battery. And spare props! (and a battery charger?) Does that FC support a lost-model buzzer?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with building drones, as this is my first one. I would assume a DJI model flight controller would support that, and if it doesn't I could just wire my one extra RC channel (Naza-M takes 5 inputs, but my RX has 6 channel outputs) to a buzzer instead. I do want to put a camera on it, so what type of camera should I use?

Comment: Sounds like you caught the fever. Already planning mods to the drone !